# Parsing out words in a string

Tags: list, haskell

I hope I was clear about my question!

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `words` from the `Prelude` will filter out spaces for you (a good way to find functions by desired type is [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=String%20-%3E%20%5BString%5D)).

```
Prelude> :t words
words :: String -> [String]
```

You just need to compose this with an appropriate filter that makes use of `Set`.  Here's a really basic one:

```
import Data.Set (Set, fromList, notMember)

parser :: String -> [String]
parser = words . filter (`notMember` delims)
   where delims = fromList ".,!?"
```

`parser "yeah.  what?"` Will return `["yeah", "what"]`.

Check out [Learn You A Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/) for some good introductory material.

Comment: Wow this is great! Could you tell me exactly when we should be composing functions by the way? They are tricky for me.

Answer (score 1):

You want [Data.List.Split](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/split/0.1.4.3/doc/html/Data-List-Split.html), which covers the vast majority of splitting use cases.

For your example, just use:

```
splitOneOf ".,!?"
```

And if you want to get rid of the "empty words" between consecutive delimiters, just use:

```
filter (not . null) . splitOneOf ".,!?"
```

If you want those delimiters to come from set that you already stored them in, then just use:

```
import qualified Data.Set as S

s :: S.Set Char

split = filter (not . null) . splitOneOf (S.toList s)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are learning, here's how to do it from scratch.

```
import qualified Data.Set as S
```

First, the set of word boundaries:

```
wordBoundaries :: S.Set Char
wordBoundaries = S.fromList " ."
```

([`Data.Set.fromList`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/containers/Data-Set.html#v%3afromList) takes a list of elements; `[Char]` is the same as `String`, which is why we can pass a string in this case.)

Next, splitting a string into words:

```
toWords :: String -> [String]
toWords = fst . foldr cons ([], True)
  where
```

The documentation for [`fst`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v%3afst) and [`foldr`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v%3afoldr) is pretty clear, but that for [`.`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v%3a.) is a bit terse if you've not encountered function composition before.

The argument given to `toWords` is fed to the `foldr cons ([], True)`. `.` then takes the result from `foldr cons ([], True)` and feeds it to `fst`. Finally, the result from `fst` is used as the result from `toWords` itself.

We have still to define `cons`:

```
    cons :: Char -> ([String], Bool) -> ([String], Bool)
    cons ch (words, startNew)
        | S.member ch wordBoundaries = (              words, True)
        | startNew                   = ([ch]        : words, False)
    cons ch (word : words, _)        = ((ch : word) : words, False)
```

Homework: work out what `cons` does and how it works. This may be easier if you first ensure you understand how `foldr` calls it.